# Bottom navigation is not showing (<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView> not working)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

For some reason, the Bottom navigation tag isn't showing inside the acitivty_main.xml, and I'm struggling to find the problem, I used `<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>` but it is not working.

Here is the activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />





</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the dependencies I'm using in the gradle just n case :

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

here is how the activity_main is displaying :

[image]

bottom_nav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notice"
        android:title="Notice"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_newsfeed"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_faculty"
        android:title="Faculty"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_faculty"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_gallery"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_about"
        android:title="About"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"/>
</menu>
```

mobile_navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.universityapp.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_notice"
        android:name="com.example.universityapp.ui.notice.NoticeFragment"
        android:label="Notice"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notice"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_faculty"
        android:name="com.example.universityapp.ui.faculty.FacultyFragment"
        android:label="Faculty"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_faculty"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_gallery"
        android:name="com.example.universityapp.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="Gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_about"
        android:name="com.example.universityapp.ui.about.AboutFragment"
        android:label="About"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about"/>


</navigation>
```

Comment: Could you add @menu/bottom_nav codes too

Comment: @harunkaraca the bottom navigation only appears after I run the app, not sure why. and yeah take a look I just added @menu/bottom_nav codes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to run your app?
for me it doesn't appear on xml, but it appears on emulator

Comment: hold on i'll try that

Comment: yeah it appeared after i ran the app but it doesn't appear before that, do you know why?